# JS variable containing undefined despite it being assigned a defined value from a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The code is meant to get all documents from a mongodb database and then create an array with all the problemIds and then get a random problemId from that array. The backend is working and the function set_problem is receiving the values correctly. The console.log inside the function also indicates the function is working because I do recieve a defined problemId when the function does console.log(problemId). However, inside the update function, id is undefined.

I was expecting that id would be defined inside the update function but it is not. Confusingly, problemId inside the set_problem function is returning a defined value when console.log(problemId) is executed. When console.log(id) inside the update function is executed, it returns undefined. I think it may have to do with the async I put in front of both of functions, but I haven't been able to figure it out so far. The url for set_problem and update is meant to be the same.

If anyone knows why this is occurring, I would greatly appreciate an explanation. Thank you for your time!

```
APILINK = // link to the backend
update(APILINK);

async function set_problem(url){
  let p_arr = []
  url = url + "action/getting_problems";
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    data.forEach(problem => {
      p_arr.push(problem._problemId);
      console.log(p_arr);
    });
  }).then(()=> {
    let problemId = p_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * p_arr.length)]
    console.log(problemId);
    return problemId;
  });
}


async function update(url){
  let id = await set_problem(url);
  url = url + id;
  console.log(url);
  console.log("id = " + id)
  // More code that is unrelated to the problem
```

Comment: In your set_problem() function, add "return await" before calling fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any return statement inside of `set_problem`, so it's implicitly returning undefined (which then gets wrapped in a promise by the `async` keyword). The return statement in the `.then` callback doesn't cause `set_problem` to return anything.

I would recommend that you don't mix async/await with then. To write your code with async/await, do this:

```
async function set_problem(url) {
  let p_arr = [];
  url = url + "action/getting_problems";
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  data.forEach((problem) => {
    p_arr.push(problem._problemId);
    console.log(p_arr);
  });
  let problemId = p_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * p_arr.length)];
  console.log(problemId);
  return problemId;
}
```

If you prefer using `.then` then at a minimum you need to add a return statement to return the promise you've created:

```
function set_problem(url) {
  let p_arr = [];
  url = url + "action/getting_problems";
  return fetch(url) // <---- added
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(function (data) {
      data.forEach((problem) => {
        p_arr.push(problem._problemId);
        console.log(p_arr);
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      let problemId = p_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * p_arr.length)];
      console.log(problemId);
      return problemId;
    });
}
```

There's also no need for a third `.then`, since the second `.then` isn't doing anything asynchronous, so you can simplify it to:

```
function set_problem(url) {
  url = url + "action/getting_problems";
  return fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(function (data) {
      let p_arr = [];
      data.forEach((problem) => {
        p_arr.push(problem._problemId);
        console.log(p_arr);
      });
      let problemId = p_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * p_arr.length)];
      console.log(problemId);
      return problemId;
    });
}
```